# Apache to serve Django Server Error (500)

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2, internal-server-error

I've a django app running on an Apache server an AWS EC2 instance. I have a Ubuntu AMI. I was just transfering one of the template files using Filezilla and now I'm getting Server Error (500) on that page. The entire web app is working fine but that page. I've no idea what went wrong.

I've even tried restarting the server `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` but the error still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable debug in your `settings.py` file and you will see what error Django throws. When debug is off, Django simply lets Apache know a server error has happened, and thus a HTTP code 500 is returned.

You may be missing a dependency.

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out. Can't believe i didn't think of that!